# "'C:\Program' is not recognized" when formatting namenode

Tags: hadoop

```
C:\Windows\system32>hdfs namenode -format
```

I am getting this error

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> '-classpath' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Comment: Please read [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop prefers not to have spaces in its filepaths, (and overall prefers not to be ran on Windows; use a Linux VM instead)

Relocate your hadoop installation somewhere other than `Program Files` and make sure to change your `HADOOP_HOME`, `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` and other related variables